# XSLT 2.0 transformation not generating proper html document

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, transformation, saxon

I am trying to use Saxon XSLT 2.0 simple transform (using Exchanger XML Editor) to generate an HTML file from an XML and an XSL document, but the data from the XML file is not getting picked up. I am assuming I have errors in my XSL stylesheet, but I am not sure where.

I have uploaded all 4 files (1 XSL, 1 XML, 1 CSS, and 1 PNG) that are needed to create the complete HTML document here...
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9o30hEqwvyDSjRsbWlZVUpyNzA

Here is my XSL stylesheet (which is the same as the one included in the link above)...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>


<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:output method="html"
      doctype-system="about:legacy-compat"
      encoding="UTF-8"
      indent="yes" />

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
         <head>
            <title>Employment Report</title>
            <link href="horizons.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
         </head>

         <body>
            <div id="wrap">
               <header>
                  <img src="horizons.png" alt="Horizons TechNet" />
               </header>

               <h1>Employment Report</h1>
               <xsl:for-each-group select="employee" group-by="gender">

                   <table id="summary">
                       <tr>
                           <th>Gender</th>
                           <td>
                               <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()" />
                           </td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                           <th>Employees</th>
                           <td>
                               <xsl:value-of select="count(current-group())" /> 
                           </td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                           <th>Average Compensation</th>
                           <td> 
                              <xsl:value-of select="avg(current-group()//salary+bonus+commission)"/>
                           </td>
                       </tr>
                   </table>


                   <table id="emptable">
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Department</th>
                            <th>Education Level</th>
                            <th>Total Compensation</th>
                        </tr>

                    <xsl:apply-templates select="employee">
                        <xsl:sort select="sum(salary+bonus+commission)" order="descending" data-type="number" />
                    </xsl:apply-templates>

                    </table>

               </xsl:for-each-group>

             </div>
         </body>

      </html>
   </xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="employee">
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="@empID" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="department" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="title" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="edLevel" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="sum(salary+bonus+commission)" /></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>   


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<xsl:for-each-group select="//employee" group-by="gender">`, for a start. And I guess you want `<xsl:apply-templates select="current-group ()">` instead of `<xsl:apply-templates select="employee">`

Additionally you have a `name` instead of a `match` attribute on the last template and in some places you use `+` and then `sum`, I guess you either want to sum items using `sum` or `+` but not both:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>



<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="html"
        doctype-system="about:legacy-compat"
        encoding="UTF-8"
        indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Employment Report</title>
                <link href="horizons.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            </head>

            <body>
                <div id="wrap">
                    <header>
                        <img src="horizons.png" alt="Horizons TechNet" />
                    </header>

                    <h1>Employment Report</h1>
                    <xsl:for-each-group select="//employee" group-by="gender">

                        <table id="summary">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Gender</th>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Employees</th>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="count(current-group())" /> 
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Average Compensation</th>
                                <td> 
                                    <xsl:value-of select="avg(current-group()/sum(salary | bonus |commission))"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>


                        <table id="emptable">
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>Department</th>
                                <th>Education Level</th>
                                <th>Total Compensation</th>
                            </tr>

                            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
                                <xsl:sort select="sum(salary | bonus | commission)" order="descending"/>
                            </xsl:apply-templates>

                        </table>

                    </xsl:for-each-group>

                </div>
            </body>

        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="employee">
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@empID" /></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="department" /></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="title" /></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="edLevel" /></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="sum(salary | bonus | commission)" /></td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>   


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: That helped a bit, thank you. Most of the document is still not showing though.

Comment: <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group ()">  displayed all the information in the xml, but not formatted in html. Also it was ALL the information on each employee, not the selected that the xsl is trying to retrieve.

Comment: @codeRed, I made some more corrections and posted a complete stylesheet as I am now at my desktop and no longer posting of my mobile phone.

Comment: Excellent Martin. That helped a lot. Everything looks great except for this... <xsl:value-of select="avg(current-group()//sum(salary | bonus |commission))"/> for some reason it isn't displaying the correct value.

Comment: @codeRed, I have corrected that expression to `<xsl:value-of select="avg(current-group()/sum(salary | bonus |commission))"/>`, not sure why I had `//` earlier, probably just a typo. Does it now give you the value you want?

Comment: Yes!! Thanks Martin. :)